# Как отрисовать фигуру а к ней подсказки по вводимым параметрам?

Tags: javascript, svg

На изображении желаемый результат (реализуемый на текущий момент). Проблема заключается в том, что при увеличении высоты и ширины текст с линией уменьшаются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И выглядит это примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как реализовать, что пересчитывать чтобы надпись с линиями были неизменны?

```js
const points = [
  {x0: 0, y0: 0, x: 0, y: 200},
  {x0: 0, y0: 200, x: 150, y: 200},
  {x0: 150, y0: 200, x: 150, y: 0},
  {x0: 150, y0: 0, x: 0, y: 0},
  {x0: 0, y0: 0, x: 0, y: 200},
  {x0: 0, y0: 200, x: 0, y: 200},
];

const path = 'M 0 200 L 150 200 L 150 0 L 0 0 L 0 200 Z';

const draw = SVG('svg-container').size(400, 400);

draw.path(path);
draw.viewbox(-40, -40, 220, 220);

let lines = [];

for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

  if (!i) {
    lines[i] = draw.line(points[i].x0 - 10, points[i].y0, points[i].x - 10, points[i].y);
    lines[i].stroke({
      width: 1,
      color: 'red'
    });
    const height_text = draw.text('Высота').attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke');
    height_text.dx(-40).dy(200 / 2 - height_text.length() / 2).transform({
      rotation: 90
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.7.1/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-container"></div>
```

```js
const points = [
  {x0: 0, y0: 0, x: 0, y: 200},
  {x0: 0, y0: 200, x: 150, y: 200},
  {x0: 150, y0: 200, x: 150, y: 0},
  {x0: 150, y0: 0, x: 0, y: 0},
  {x0: 0, y0: 0, x: 0, y: 200},
  {x0: 0, y0: 200, x: 0, y: 200},
];

const width = 1000;

const path = 'M 0 200 L 150 200 L 150 0 L 0 0 L 0 200 Z';

const draw = SVG('svg-container').size(400, 400);

draw.rect(width, width);

draw.viewbox(-40, -40, width+20, width+20);

let lines = [];

for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

  if (!i) {
    lines[i] = draw.line(points[i].x0 - 10, points[i].y0, points[i].x - 10, points[i].y);
    lines[i].stroke({
      width: 1,
      color: 'red'
    });
    const height_text = draw.text('Высота').attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke');
    height_text.dx(-40).dy(200 / 2 - height_text.length() / 2).transform({
      rotation: 90
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.7.1/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-container"></div>
```

Comment: Ну и где код???

Comment: @Qwertiy Докидывал)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, хочется сохранить надпись и толщину линии при любых размерах прямоугольника. Но, при этом прямоугольник должен не маленьким, а растягиваться по ширине и высоте.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  самого `svg`?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, не меняется.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98711/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-doox911).

Comment: нужно вычислять толщину линии по пропорции, например во втором примере сделать  толщину не 1 а `{width: 1/220*width}` (умножить на отношение всот картинок, которые Вы создаете)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я так понял, это мы вычислим коэффициент `K`. Пожалуйста, оформите в виде ответа с небольшим примером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как вы меняете `viewBox` это приводит к изменению масштаба изображения, соответственно толщину линий необходимо считать исходя из соотношений масштабов:

```
{width: 1/220*width}
```

```js
const points = [
  {x0: 0, y0: 0, x: 0, y: 200},
  {x0: 0, y0: 200, x: 150, y: 200},
  {x0: 150, y0: 200, x: 150, y: 0},
  {x0: 150, y0: 0, x: 0, y: 0},
  {x0: 0, y0: 0, x: 0, y: 200},
  {x0: 0, y0: 200, x: 0, y: 200},
];

const width = 1000;

const path = 'M 0 200 L 150 200 L 150 0 L 0 0 L 0 200 Z';

const draw = SVG('svg-container').size(400, 400);

draw.rect(width, width);

draw.viewbox(-40, -40, width+20, width+20);

let lines = [];

for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

  if (!i) {
    lines[i] = draw.line(points[i].x0 - 10, points[i].y0, points[i].x - 10, points[i].y);
    lines[i].stroke({
      width: 1/220*width,
      color: 'red'
    });
    const height_text = draw.text('Высота').attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke');
    height_text.dx(-40).dy(200 / 2 - height_text.length() / 2).transform({
      rotation: 90
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.7.1/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-container"></div>
```

Comment: А текст рядом с линией?)

Comment: @doox911 fontSize по той же формуле и позиционирование менять придется

Comment: Спасибо. Завтра протестю)